# How to show that for every surface exists only finitely many non-isomorphic embeddable 7-regular graphs?

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, algebraic-topology

Can you give me some hints how to show that for every surface exists only finitely many non-isomorphic 7-regular graphs that can be embedded into that surface?

Answer (score 0):

This is only true if you disallow self loops on vertices and disallow multiple edges between the same pair of vertices.
Let's first think about 4-regular graphs.  If you only allow your graph to have $n$ vertices, are there finitely or infinitely many isomorphism types of graphs?

Now try to draw a biggest possible 4-regular graph on a torus.  Is there a maximum to the number of vertices your graph can have?  Try the same thing for a genus two surface $\Sigma_2$.  What's the biggest possible number of vertices?  What is it about the complementary regions in $\Sigma_2$ that seems to prevent the addition of more vertices?

The graph is cutting up your surface into complementary regions.  What classical theorem relates a topological invariant of the surface to ways of cutting it up into polyhedra?